# How to shrink a csv file to use it for a neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Got a python code for a neural network. I want to train the network to learn if a picture is a technical drawing or not. Therefore I got a set of training images, around 45 files, and a set of test images, around 2000 files. I reshaped all files into 28x28 large grayscale images and converted them into a train and a test csv file. Then I adjusted the output nodes and changed the path to both csvfiles. The problem is that the csv files are too large. The `test.csv` is already at 14GB plus. As far as I know it is not possible to test the neural network with such a big test file, since my computer is limited by 8GB of memory. Is there any way to shrink the csv file without loosing information?

This is the code for the neural network:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from tqdm import tqdm

class neuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inode = inputnodes
        self.hnode = hiddennodes
        self.onode = outputnodes
# =============================================================================
#         self.wih=np.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.inode,-0.5),(self.hnode,self.inode))
#         self.who=np.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnode,-0.5),(self.onode,self.hnode))
# =============================================================================
        self.wih = np.random.normal(0, pow(self.hnode, -0.5), (self.hnode, self.inode))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0, pow(self.onode, -0.5), (self.onode, self.hnode))
        self.lr = learningrate
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        pass

    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        output_errors = targets - final_outputs
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors) 
        self.who += self.lr * np.dot((output_errors * final_outputs 
        * (1.0 - final_outputs)), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))
        self.wih += self.lr * np.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs 
        * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)), np.transpose(inputs))
        pass

    def test(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        return final_outputs

input_nodes = 784
hidden_nodes = 500
output_nodes = 100000
learning_rate = 0.1
epochs = 5

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes, learning_rate)
training_data_file = open("C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/train.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()

for e in range(epochs):
    for record in tqdm(training_data_list):
        all_values = record.split(',')
        inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
        targets = np.zeros(output_nodes) + 0.01
        targets[int(float(all_values[0]))] = 0.99
        n.train(inputs, targets)
        pass
    pass

test_data_file = open("C:/Users/Anwender/Documents/Uni/KI/Python/test.csv", 'r')
test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines()
test_data_file.close()

scorecard = []
for record in test_data_list:
    all_values = record.split(',')
    correct_label = int(all_values[0])
    inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
    outputs = n.test(inputs)
    label = np.argmax(outputs)
    if (label == correct_label):
        scorecard.append(1)
    else:
        scorecard.append(0)
        pass
    pass

scorecard_array = np.asarray(scorecard)
print ("Genauigkeit = ", scorecard_array.sum() / scorecard_array.size)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to feed _the whole data_ into the network. You can split it into relatively small chunks and train the network on multiple chunks, while having only some of them loaded at once: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network

Comment: Any idea how I could implement such a batch size process? Sadly, I'am an absolute beginner in python. I hardly understand the python code of the neural network but have to finish this project. Would be appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: First, try loading only a part of the file in `training_data_list`. Say, the first `n` lines. Then your code will be trained only on this single chunk. Next, you can create a function that would return `n` random lines from the file. For example, you could create a new chunk at the beginning of each new epoch. So, the code may look like: `for e in range(epochs): for record in tqdm(get_chunk()): # train on this record`.